# Dragon Ball Xenoverse collecters edition

Tags: steam

I'm planning on getting Dragon Ball Xenoverse for PC via steam. If you pre-order you get special content but I want to wait for release so i can see how it turns out. The same content is in the collectors edition. Can you purchase the collectors edition even after the game is out for a while so i can see some reviews first?

Comment: We can't possible give you a definitive answer to that question, because we don't know the future and it would be pure speculation. That being said, if there is not explicit statement saying so, why do you think would the collector's edition become unavailable when the game is out?

Answer (score 1):

They don't offer the Collector's Edition on Steam. It might become available eventually. If you try to pre-order from the [website](http://www.dragonballxenoverse.com/en/), the Collector's Edition is only available for consoles (I only checked Steam and Xbox one). It ain't available for Steam.

Also, it doesn't look like the Collector's Edition includes the pre-order content.

So if you wish to wait, you'll miss out on the pre-order content only on PC. The Collector's Edition is surely in limited quantity, so it might not be available after the game is officially out but, usually, it does for some time.